# Mendeley 1.19 update makes cpu 102%, How to check causes of this?

Tags: 16.04, cpu-load, mendeley

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After upgrading to Mendeley Desktop 1.19 edition CPU runs over 100%. As I check htop there is not any other processes running to have over 100% CPU.

How can I check What is wrong, or what causes this situation?

[image: htop result for mendeley desktop 1.19]

Here is my Mendeley version info:

[image: Mendeley Desktop 1.19 Linux distribution]

I am editing to add bug report response by email from Mendeley:
[image: Mendeley 1.19 bug report response]

**2018-06-18 Edit: The bug was solved on version 1.19.1.**

Comment: "How can I check What is wrong" with some piece of software is too broad. File a bug report, if you can find its developers.

Comment: Downgrade Mendeley back to an earlier version. Mendeley 1.19 has an excessive CPU usage bug.

Comment: I found a work-around [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-downgrade-aur-package/48296/8):
For me it worked with the following modification:
`mendeleydesktop & (sleep 5; cpulimit -l 10 -p $(pidof mendeleydesktop))`
But be aware that then Mendeley is a pain to use (much slower GUI response).

Comment: @mikewhatever I've emailed them and added response by editing question. I was writing it to askubuntu cause of using it as OS. And other people using Ubuntu facing this problem can find answer.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with v1.19 and it utilizes 100 % of CPU usage. My ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS. Is it possible to downgrade the current version.

Comment: They wrote that BUG will be fixed on next update v1.20. @RubanrajRavichandran

Comment: @karel - where can i get an earler version? the mendley site does not have any download link for earlier versions.

Comment: @infoclogged You can find the Mendeley Desktop old versions webpage at: https://www.mendeley.com/autoupdates/installers/1.6. In addition to the old release (Mendeley Desktop 1.6 for Ubuntu (64-bit)) there is also a preview release.

Comment: 1.6 is version very old, its better to wait for new update with bug fix.

Comment: The bug Is resolved in 1.19.1 version

Comment: @karel, how did you find this link?.. Or did you already have a bookmark in your browser?.. On the Mendeley site, I cant anything such as "previous versions".  Just curious.. The bug is however already fixed in 1.19.1

Comment: @infoclogged I don't have a system as such except that I've been an Ask Ubuntu user for a long time and an Ubuntu Forums user before that and I have a good memory.

Comment: For the record, I also verified the bug in new version 1.19.1 and its resolved. No more 100 % CPU usage.